# Host a Django Application on Digital Ocean with ssl obtained from Let's Encrypt Certbot as at Sept 2019

Tags: django, ssl, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to enable ssl on my domain name and after I follow the steps on the certbot website to set up ssl for my new domain I get an error port 80 is already in use when I run `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`.

I'm using nginx and that's what shows up on my index page. I want to test out the https before I bind with gunicorn to that port but would it work then.

I tried to do this before two weeks ago and it worked perfectly fine. Installed nginx and ssl cert and ran `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`
and it was working

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `runserver` while nginx is running, because nginx is using port 80. You have a few options if you need to use `runserver`:

- open another port through the Digital Ocean networking options in the web portal on which to run runserver (maybe port 8000?)
- stop the nginx service when you need to use `runserver`

One thing I don't understand is why you need to run `runserver` if you've got nginx and gunicorn. I'm guessing that two weeks ago when you ran `runserver` you didn't have the nginx daemon running. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I don't have gunicorn installed yet. The app is still in it's testing stages and I need to test it on https. If the nginx daemon isn't running would the site still be accessible over https?